# Adding content to others' answers

Tags: discussion, editing

I know one or two of you might have noticed me adding content like pictures or links. I hope this does not annoy you - it is just that your answers are the correct answers in my opinion, but I do enjoy adding photos wherever possible.  It's like a picture is worth a thousand words.

Is this is annoying, upsetting or against any rules?

Answer (score 7):

If photos and links improve the post (be it a question or answer) then that's OK. In fact it's welcomed.

The OP is notified of edits to posts so they can double check and roll back if necessary.

Comment: Yes, it's very much welcomed!

Answer (score 6):

I think this is great! Certainly a way better solution than posting a new answer that repeats most of what is already included in another answer but with a picture.

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, photos and links are a fantastic edit, and much appreciated.   It's also a big help to low-rep users who can't post themselves.

I tend to put new text content in a comment.  While I realize that all answers are property of "The Community"  I try not to change the basic answer other than for readability.

Comment: Using this mechanism can help keep things very clear, however, one of the regular activities we undertake over on Security SE is to go through old questions, rolling up useful comments into answers and deleting the bad comments, so it does add some effort.

Comment: Are you suggesting we should edit directly?  Perhaps with a comment -- I edited xxx into your answer. Rollback if you want?

Comment: If there is an extra piece of info that would complete a question, it can make sense, yes. The aim at the end of the day is to get the best possible answers. Commenting or in some way letting the individual know is probably the polite way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

In general, I think it is useful, especially if there are no pictures or links in the original. I think we need to be careful if there are existing examples. In that case, post a new answer.

On the other hand, maybe it would be better to provide a new answer that references the earlier, such as "Here are examples of the *reverse faramus* that ppumkin described in an earlier answer."